# Singleton when constructing an object

Tags: python, class

I have a simple class:

```
class Weather_data():
    def __init__(self, latitude=None, longitude=None, date=None):
        self.latitude = latitude,
        self.longitude = longitude,
        self.request_date = date
```

When I construct an object, I have a singleton recorded as latitude or longitude:

```
>>> w2=Weather_data(1.3,1.9,datetime.datetime.now())
>>> w2.latitude
(1.3,)
```

Why is it so?

Bonus: I have another class:

```
class Pricer():

    def __init__(self, realization_date=None, latitude=None, longitude=None, amount_covered=None):
        self.realization_date = realization_date
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
```

And when I contract an object I get a float an not a tuple:

```
>>> p2=Pricer(datetime.datetime.now(),1.3,1.9,100)
>>> p2.latitude
1.3
```

I have no idea of the difference between those 2 classes.

Comment: `latitude,` - a comma makes it a tuple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the commas after these lines in your first example, like so:

```
self.latitude = latitude
self.longitude = longitude
```

The commas are telling Python to create tuples that include `latitude` and `longitude`. In the second object, you don't have the commas, and thus you get `float`s as output.

Comment: Glad to help! But as the saying goes:
"Sometimes it pays to stay in bed on Monday, rather than spending the rest of the week debugging Monday’s code.”
— Christopher Thompson